# Sql Calculating history from migrated data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data like given below.

[image: Table with some sample data]

The problem is, I have to calculate the History on the basis of number. Suppose number is unique identity of a "submission form". Every time there is a change in value of any column i have to extract it change.

Below is structure for history table.

[image: Structure of history table]

Now we have two form in system. with number 2 and 4.
So the result history data should look like this.

[image: Result of history table for form number 2 and 4]

Comment: What database you use MYSQL or MSSQL as mentioned in tags?

Comment: @user3432824 - I've fixed question tags for you. Next time please do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL you can use function [LAG() OVER ()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) to get previous value.

```
WITH CT AS
(
  SELECT
       ID,
       number as submissionID, 
       'amount' as Field,
       LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY ID)as OldValue,
       amount as NewValue
  FROM T
) 

SELECT * FROM CT 
WHERE OldValue IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY submissionID,ID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61614/6)</kbd>

Another way is to use ROW_NUMBER() function to connect current record with the previous so you can get all values from the previous record:

```
WITH CT AS
(
  SELECT
       T.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY ID DESC)as RowNum
  FROM T
) 

SELECT CT.*,CT2.amount as oldValue FROM CT 
JOIN CT as CT2 on CT.Number=CT2.Number 
     AND CT.RowNum+1=CT2.RowNum
ORDER BY CT.number,CT.ID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61614/11)</kbd>

Comment: But there will be more than one column, like amount, address, city, state.

Comment: @user3432824 I added one more query to help with this issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I added more column in this table, after that result was not what i was expecting. Please add a one more column and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  d1.number,
  'amount' as field,
  d1.amount as newValue,
  d2.amount as oldValue
from data d1 join data d2 on d1.number=d2.number and d1.id=d2.id-1
```

Won't work if id have gaps but you caan use row number to replace the id's solution

Comment: But there will be more than one column, like amount, address, city, state.

Comment: then add them in the ON d1.field=d2.field